# Snack.expo Attempted to assign to readonly property @react-navigation/native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-v5

Link: [snack](https://snack.expo.io/NpIwPZ!uo)

It is based on an example of the component: `react-native-animated-tabbar`.

But it seems that the problem is on the module `@react-navigation/native`, which on snack.expo does not seem to work properly, giving me the following error:

```
Device: (857:881) Attempted to assign to readonly property.
  Evaluating module://@react-navigation/native.js
  Evaluating module://App.tsx.js
  Loading module://App.tsx
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import RootScreen from './screens/Root';
import BubbleScreen from './screens/Bubble';
import BubbleStyledScreen from './screens/BubbleStyled';
import BubbleRTLScreen from './screens/BubbleRTL';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Root" headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={RootScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Bubble" component={BubbleScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="BubbleStyled" component={BubbleStyledScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="BubbleRTL" component={BubbleRTLScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```